# Is there a link between Elliott-Halberstam and weak Hardy-Littlewood-Goldbach conjectures?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems, prime-constellations

Let $\theta$ be such that $EH(\theta)$ holds, where $EH$ stands for Elliott-Halberstam. Can one get an explicit lower bound $\delta_{\theta}$ for the quantity $\delta$ appearing in the weak Hardy-Littlewood-Goldbach stated in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022314X21002031? In particular, would Elliott-Halberstam conjecture imply the weak Hardy-Littlewood-Goldbach conjecture for some $\delta$ close to $1$?

Indeed it is known that the greater $\theta$ is, the smaller the quantity $l_{k}(\theta):=\lim\inf p_{n+k}-p_{n}$ gets.
Define $r_{0}(m)$ as the smallest non negative integer $r$ such that both $m-r$ and $m+r$ are prime and $k_{0}(m):=\pi(m+r_{0}(m))-\pi(m-r_{0}(m))$. I call such an integer $r$ a primality radius of $m$.
Say also that an integer $m$ is $k$-central if $k_{0}(m)=k$ and denote by $\mathbb{N}_{k}$ the set of $k$-central integers.

Then one has $l_{k}(\theta)=2\lim\inf_{m\in\mathbb{N}_{k}}r_{0}(m)$, so the greater $\theta$ is, the smaller $r_{0}$ and very likely the more numerous primality radii of an integer of given magnitude get.

Comment: Is EH conjecture even known to imply $G(n)>0$ for some large $n$? The only result along these lines I found is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.03811), which relies on EH together with a "twisted" version of EH.

Comment: Do you mean for at least one value of $n$ or any sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: By the way, I think $\Lambda(n)$ should be replaced with $y$ in the second sum of the definition of $EH_{\mu}$ in the paper you quote.

Comment: I meant "sufficiently large $n$". As for the second comment - I don't think so, but if you believe that, feel free to contact the authors to let them know.